# How to load the only css file based on screen size in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I was having a deep look on websites like `ebay, facebook,amazon, etc` and find out when user go to their website, they detect the monitor screen resolution/size and store it in cookies and load the css file based on screen resolution.

How to implement this scenario in asp.net. 
I have a responsive layout and `using media queries` as  per resolution changes.

But now i want to fix the user to first detect their screen resolution and only load the css file based on that result.

Any suggestions!!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<link id="size-stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" />
```

Comment: Do you look on google ? I found too many examples, here is one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071521/how-to-load-different-css-file-depending-on-window-width-smaller-size-not-recog

Comment: Try to understand the question first!!
i think you donot read my question i didnot ask for loading css based on media. for simplicity go to facebook and inspect in cookies you found the screen size. then increase or decrease the width height of browser, it will not load the responsive css. but if you login from the mobile it will show the mobile css. I want to implement this.

Comment: Please note, I do not downvote the question (neither have vote for anything yet). Now the size of the browser can be get in real time only with javascript, and then you send this size to code behind and use it. Other way is to read the browser signature, and other way is the css it self.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flowing code.

- You have to put this `JavaScript` into `<head>` tag.

  ```
  $(function () 
    {
      var ScrnHeight = $(window).height();
      var ScrnWidth = $(window).width();

      if (ScrnWidth <= 360) { // for mobile view
          $("<link/>", {
              rel: "stylesheet",
              type: "text/css",
              href: "/styles/mobile.css"
          }).appendTo("head");
      }
      else { // for desktop view 
          $("<link/>", {
              rel: "stylesheet",
              type: "text/css",
              href: "/styles/main.css"
          }).appendTo("head");
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: @Hassaan Khan - If answer is useful, click on 'correct' or 'upvote' so it will helps other to find out correct solution.

Comment: sorry i didnot ask for that