# Media property issue in head

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I don't want a stylesheet to be loaded on mobile devices, so I used the

```
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" media="max-width:1000px">
```

But it doesn't work! It loads the stylesheet anyway on mobile.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `max-width` with `min-width`

Answer (score 0):

1. One thing you can try: if you previously loaded the stylesheet on the mobile, try clearing the cache or using a different mobile phone to see what happens.
2. Other than that i think your code looks right also add type to the tag but i don't think it will change anything: `<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:1000px)" type="text/css">`
3. you can also check this question: [Loading difference styles depending on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071521/how-to-load-different-css-file-depending-on-window-width-smaller-size-not-recog)